# Modifying Wordpress PHP dynamic content

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My page is [bewitcheryinc.com](http://bewitcheryinc.com) 
I am trying to re-arrange my home page. I need to switch the promotional area (section with 3 rectangles) with the text below it. I need to have the text displayed first and then the promotional area (section with 3 rectangles). I have contacted theme support, and they told me that the content is dynamic and the only solution to try is to replace header.php with the following code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Displays the header content
 *
 * @package Theme Freesia
 * @subpackage Edge
 * @since Edge 1.0
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<?php
$edge_settings = edge_get_theme_options(); ?>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<!-- Masthead ============================================= -->
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <?php if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_header_markup' ) ) {
            if ( is_header_video_active() && ( has_header_video() || is_customize_preview() ) ) {
                echo '<div class="custom-header">
                    <div class="custom-header-media">';
                the_custom_header_markup();
                echo '</div>
                </div>';
            }else{ 
                if ( has_header_image() ) {?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/'));?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-image" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display'));?>" /> </a>
                <?php }
            }
        } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/'));?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-image" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display'));?>" /> </a>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="top-header">
            <div class="container clearfix">
                <?php
                if( is_active_sidebar( 'edge_header_info' )) {
                    dynamic_sidebar( 'edge_header_info' );
                }
                if($edge_settings['edge_top_social_icons'] == 0):
                    echo '<div class="header-social-block">';
                        do_action('social_links');
                    echo '</div>'.'<!-- end .header-social-block -->';
                endif;
                 do_action('edge_site_branding'); ?>
            </div> <!-- end .container -->
        </div> <!-- end .top-header -->
        <!-- Main Header============================================= -->
                <div id="sticky_header">
                    <div class="container clearfix">
                        <h3 class="nav-site-title">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/'));?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display'));?>"><?php bloginfo('name');?></a>
                        </h3>
                    <!-- end .nav-site-title -->
                        <!-- Main Nav ============================================= -->
                        <?php
                            if (has_nav_menu('primary')) { ?>
                        <?php $args = array(
                            'theme_location' => 'primary',
                            'container'      => '',
                            'items_wrap'     => '<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu">%3$s</ul>',
                            ); ?>
                        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation clearfix">
                            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="line-one"></span>
                                <span class="line-two"></span>
                                <span class="line-three"></span>
                            </button>
                            <!-- end .menu-toggle -->
                            <?php wp_nav_menu($args);//extract the content from apperance-> nav menu ?>
                        </nav> <!-- end #site-navigation -->
                        <?php } else {// extract the content from page menu only ?>
                        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation clearfix">
                            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="line-one"></span>
                                <span class="line-two"></span>
                                <span class="line-three"></span>
                            </button>
                        <!-- end .menu-toggle -->
                            <?php   wp_page_menu(array('menu_class' => 'menu', 'items_wrap'     => '<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu">%3$s</ul>')); ?>
                        </nav> <!-- end #site-navigation -->
                        <?php }
                        $search_form = $edge_settings['edge_search_custom_header'];
                        if (1 != $search_form) { ?>
                            <div id="search-toggle" class="header-search"></div>
                            <div id="search-box" class="clearfix">
                                <?php get_search_form();?>
                            </div>  <!-- end #search-box -->
                        <?php } 

            echo '</div> <!-- end .container -->
            </div> <!-- end #sticky_header -->';
        $enable_slider = $edge_settings['edge_enable_slider'];
        edge_slider_value();
        if ($enable_slider=='frontpage'|| $enable_slider=='enitresite'){
            if(is_front_page() && ($enable_slider=='frontpage') ) {
                if($edge_settings['edge_slider_type'] == 'default_slider') {
                        edge_page_sliders();
                }else{
                    if(class_exists('Edge_Plus_Features')):
                        edge_image_sliders();
                    endif;
                }
            }
            if($enable_slider=='enitresite'){
                if($edge_settings['edge_slider_type'] == 'default_slider') {
                        edge_page_sliders();
                }else{
                    if(class_exists('Edge_Plus_Features')):
                        edge_image_sliders();
                    endif;
                }
            }
        } ?>
</header> <!-- end #masthead -->
<!-- Main Page Start ============================================= -->
<div id="content">
<div class="container clearfix">
<?php 
if(is_front_page()){
    if( have_posts() ) {
        while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
        }
    } else { ?>
    <h2 class="entry-title"> <?php esc_html_e( 'No Posts Found.', 'edge' ); ?> </h2>
    <?php }

    do_action('edge_display_frontpage_features');
}
if(!is_home()){?>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo edge_header_title(); ?></h1>
        <!-- .page-title -->
        <?php edge_breadcrumb(); ?>
        <!-- .breadcrumb -->
    </div>
    <!-- .page-header -->
<?php }
```

After I replace headr.php, I have to add the following css:

```
.home .entry-header, .home .entry-meta, section#post-417, .home .entry-footer {
display:none;
}
```

When I follow these instructions, the home page displays my original page text as a blog post with "read more" tags, along with the meta tags. The read more link links back to the home page. I simply want the front page to display my page title, some text, and then the promotional picture boxes.

If it is helpful, I beleive that when promotional area is turned on, the theme uses front-page-feature.php template instead of an index page. It is bellow.

```
<?php
function edge_frontpage_features(){
    $edge_settings = edge_get_theme_options();
    if($edge_settings['edge_disable_features'] != 1){
        $edge_features = '';
        $edge_total_page_no = 0; 
        $edge_list_page = array();
        for( $i = 1; $i <= $edge_settings['edge_total_features']; $i++ ){
            if( isset ( $edge_settings['edge_frontpage_features_' . $i] ) && $edge_settings['edge_frontpage_features_' . $i] > 0 ){
                $edge_total_page_no++;

                $edge_list_page =   array_merge( $edge_list_page, array( $edge_settings['edge_frontpage_features_' . $i] ) );
            }

        }
        if ( !empty( $edge_list_page ) && $edge_total_page_no > 0 ) {
            echo '<!-- Promotional Area ============================================= -->';
                $edge_features  .= '<div class="promonational-area">';
                                $get_featured_posts         = new WP_Query(array(
                                'posts_per_page'        => $edge_settings['edge_total_features'],
                                'post_type'             => array('page'),
                                'post__in'              => $edge_list_page,
                                'orderby'               => 'post__in',
                            ));
                    $edge_features .= '<div class="column clearfix">';
                $j = 1;
                while ($get_featured_posts->have_posts()):$get_featured_posts->the_post();
                $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id,'pixgraphy_promotional_image');
                            $excerpt                     = get_the_excerpt();
                    $edge_features .= '<div class="three-column">';
                    if ($image_attributes) {
                        $edge_features  .= '<div class="promonational-img" title="'.the_title('', '', false).'"' .' style="background-image:url(' ."'" .esc_url($image_attributes[0])."'" .')"> <a class="promonational-link" href="'.get_the_permalink().'"></a>   ';
                        $edge_features .= '<div class="promonational-overlay">
                                <h4>'.get_the_title().'</h4></div></div>';
                    }
                    $edge_features  .='</div><!-- end .three-column -->';
                    $j++;
                    endwhile;
                    $edge_features  .='</div><!-- .end column-->';
                    $edge_features  .='</div><!-- end .promonational-area -->';
                }
        echo $edge_features;
    }
        wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_action('edge_display_frontpage_features','edge_frontpage_features');
```

Can anyone help? I am not proficient obviously in PHP/WordPress at all. Thank you!

Comment: Create a new template for your page in the theme directory, select that template on the page right side menu (Page Attributes).

Comment: If you can paste your home page template here, it'd be easy to figure out probably. It doesn't look like its complicated. I bet you can switch them just in the content template part file.

Comment: @TurtleTread Thank you! I have added the rest of the templates of my site. Does it help in figuring out how to switch the sections?

Comment: @Scuzzy I have added some more templates to the post. For clarity. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

In index.php move the

`if(is_front_page()){
    do_action('edge_display_frontpage_features');
}`

right before

```
get_template_part( 'pagination', 'none' );
```

in header.php.

This would put the front-page feature after the 'main' content in the primary section of the post. Now you need to figure out how to put the right post content for the text. Currently it seems like it's not fetching the correct post type. It's probably the sample post in the post post type.

But is the text supposed to be static or changes with your recently posted content? If its supposed to static, you should go in **Settings->Reading** in the admin dashboard and **set the front-page to a static page** and then you can put in the text into that page content.

Comment: Thank you but it does absolutely nothing. Ne effect on anything at all.

Comment: So I think your current page may not be built by index.php. What's the template your front page is using?..do you have the link to the theme you installed?

Comment: The theme I am using is https://wordpress.org/themes/edge/

The theme developers are saying it is not designed to do what I want it to do but they want to help. They said replace the header.php with new code they provided and one css tweak. I execute their solution, I’m getting the text that want on top of the featured area but that text begins to look like a Post with meta tags and read more sign. When I click on read more it keeps taking me to a home page. I have edited the original post here to with new header.php that they provided and the front page that theme is using.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at this! I really appreciate it!

Comment: P.S. The text is static. I have the front page set to static as well.

Comment: If the text is static, it should be easy. You just copy the text html block and put it in the beginning of the edge_frontpage_features() function. You probably need to figure out some styling issues to make it look good.